# How to add delays in thread-safe manner (TcpClient)

Tags: c#, multithreading, telnet

I'm creating a project that will read in a list of emails and using external libraries, will look up the MX records for that domain, and use telnet to determine whether or not that email exists.

I have managed to make it slightly work so far - however due to how fast the code runs, I believe I'm attempting to read the server's response quicker than it is being sent. (I assume this, as the code will  return empty strings when run without debugging, with breakpoints it returns everything fine.)

To counter-act this I added Thread.Sleep() in areas around the code so I could wait for the response, this works but it locks the thread and stops responding for several minutes.

How would I be able to perform this task without locking the UI?
Here is the code from the class where the issue is -

```
class TelnetConnection
{
    TcpClient tcpClient;
    List<char> reply;
    public TelnetConnection(string hostname, int port)
    {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient(); 
        tcpClient.BeginConnect(hostname, port, null, null);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    public List<char> GetReply()
    {
        reply = new List<char>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (tcpClient.Available > 0)
        {
            ParseTelnet(sb);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
        {
            reply.Add(sb[i]);
        }
        return reply;
    }
    public List<char> Greet(string greeting)
    {
        WriteLine(greeting);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return GetReply();
    }
    public List<char> MailFrom(string mailFrom)
    {
        WriteLine(string.Concat("MAIL FROM: <", mailFrom, ">"));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return GetReply();
    }
    public List<char> RcptTo(string rcptTo)
    {
        WriteLine(string.Concat("RCPT TO: <", rcptTo, ">"));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return GetReply();
    }

    public void WriteLine(string cmd)
    {
        Write(cmd + "\n");
    }

    public void Write(string cmd)
    {
        if (!tcpClient.Connected) return;
        byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF", "\0xFF\0xFF"));
        tcpClient.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return tcpClient.Connected; }
    }

    // Method from external library
    void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
    {
            try
            {
                int input = tcpClient.GetStream().ReadByte();
                switch (input)
                {
                    case -1:
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                        // interpret as command
                        int inputverb = tcpClient.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputverb == -1) break;
                        switch (inputverb)
                        {
                            case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                                //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                                sb.Append(inputverb);
                                break;
                            case (int)Verbs.DO:
                            case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                            case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                            case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                                // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                                int inputoption = tcpClient.GetStream().ReadByte();
                                if (inputoption == -1) break;
                                tcpClient.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                                if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA)
                                    tcpClient.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL : (byte)Verbs.DO);
                                else
                                    tcpClient.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT);
                                tcpClient.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append((char)input);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnettelnet/) to make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the Sleeps. You simply can't know how long it will take for the server to respond.

Instead, agree upon a marker in the data that is sent from server to client and marks the end of the response.

In the GetReplay read from the stream until you encounter the marker and then return.

**EDIT** it looks like the ParseTelnet method tries to do something like this. Make sure the server is sending what you are expecting.

An alternative is to have the server send the length of the reply first so all the client has to do is read that amount of bytes.

An agreement like this is called a protocol.

To prevent blocking the UI perform the sending and reading asynchronously by using the *Async methods of the NetworkStream.

Comment: Besides "protocol" the other term to look for while googling is ["Message Framing"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - interesting article, nice to see my ideas reflected :) thanks.